# Is there an alternative to writeFields?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

[This article](https://medium.com/day4/firebases-firestore-rules-what-the-f-part-2-fed76a9db25#428c) stated that "[writeFields] is now deprecated".
Additionally, I cannot find any documentation for `writeFields`, it is not even listed as part of [`Request`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request) in the documentation anymore.

### Problem

The problem I am facing with Cloud Firestore Security Rules is that verifying that only particular fields are modified requires massive amounts of conditions.
For example, if I want to verify that the only modified value of a document is `cakes`, I have to write the following rule:

```js
allow update: if request.resource.data.size() == 20
              && request.resource.data.likes == resource.data.likes
              && request.resource.data.name == resource.data.name
              && request.resource.data.date == resource.data.date
              && request.resource.data.body == resource.data.body
              && request.resource.data.title == resource.data.title
              && request.resource.data.tags == resource.data.tags
              && request.resource.data.comments == resource.data.comments
              && request.resource.data.answers == resource.data.answers
              && request.resource.data.awards == resource.data.awards
              && request.resource.data.image == resource.data.image
              && request.resource.data.link == resource.data.link
              && request.resource.data.format == resource.data.format
              && request.resource.data.type == resource.data.type
              && request.resource.data.user == resource.data.user
              && request.resource.data.views == resource.data.views
              && request.resource.data.reports == resource.data.reports
              && request.resource.data.roles == resource.data.roles
              && request.resource.data.category == resource.data.category
              && request.resource.data.votes == resource.data.votes
              && request.resource.data.cakes is int;
```

Using `writeFields`, the **exact same** rule would have looked like this:

```dart
allow update: if request.writeFields.hasOnly(['cakes']) && request.resource.data.cakes is int;
```

What can I do to decrease the code size of my rules / what is the alternative to `writeFields`?

### Limits

There are two [limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-behavior#security_rule_limits) mentioned in the documentation that make this problem even worse:

- Maximum number of expressions evaluated per request:     1,000
- Maximum size of a ruleset:   64 KB

I expect to reach both of these at some point with this limitation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! There is now a replacement called "Map Diffs". Check this syntax out:

```
allow update: if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['cakes']) 
              && request.resource.data.cakes is int;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, what you're doing right now is currently your best option.

The Firebase rules team is working on a language improvement to make it easier to compare/diff map type objects, which will drastically cut down on the number of expressions it takes to do this sort of thing, but there is no timeline for that right now.  Please stay tuned.

Answer (score 0):

I end up writing these helper function:

```js
// returns true if all the fields changed are contained in the array parameter
function onlyAllowedFields(fieldsArray) {  
  return fieldsArray.toSet().hasAll(request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys());
}

// returns true if none of the fields are changed
function noneOfDisallowedFields(fieldsArray) {  
  return request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasAny(fieldsArray.toSet()) == false
}
```

I found more helpful this way instead of using hasOnly() that would require that all fields that could be changed must have been changed.