# What is MapDiff in Cloud Firestore Security Rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have heard of a new **`MapDiff`** feature in Cloud Firestore Security rules.

I want to use this to more efficiently solve the [problem described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58681738/6509751), i.e. avoid having to write out the following:

```js
allow update: if request.resource.data.size() == 6
              && request.resource.data.likes == resource.data.likes
              && request.resource.data.name == resource.data.name
              && request.resource.data.date == resource.data.date
              && request.resource.data.body == resource.data.body
              && request.resource.data.title == resource.data.title
              && request.resource.data.cakes is int;
```

In the past, `writeFields` existed, but they are [unsupported now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58681738/6509751).

How can I effeciently (concerning code conciseness) check if only a single field has been altered and use `MapDiff` in general?

Comment: Any reason why you didn't answer the other questions that you linked out to?  This is technically a dup, and has been asked several times.

Comment: In that case, this is really good material for a blog post, since it's addressing a rather broad question.

Comment: @DougStevenson I use StackOverflow for this and this is also encouraged as far as I am concerned: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: The issue isn't that you're answering your own question. I do that too.  The issue is that the question is rather broad, and a blog post is probably a better vehicle for this sort of expansive topic. You can even make money off Medium posts, which are better than SO points, if you ask me.

Comment: Simply post to medium and tell them how to deposit money into a bank account.

Comment: @PeterHaddad Today, I make over $60/month among the last three posts I've done. It's overall a better vehicle for lengthy content such as tutorials.  Stack Overflow is good for relatively short answer to specific questions.  The question in this post is not very specific: *"how do I use MapDiff in general"*.

Comment: FWIW, I strongly disagree with @DougStevenson. I always saw medium as a random quality content and don't have time to check every author's bio. If a google search leads to a SO answer, it will most of the time answer my question or will contain useful information to narrow my search or give me new pointers on what I should look for.
I also feel that OP's answer is still more concise, readable and understandable than the official documentation on this topic (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### TL;DR

```js
allow update: if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['cakes'])
              && request.resource.data.cakes is int;
```

## `MapDiff` explanation

[`rules.MapDiff`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff) is a *powerful feature* recently added to Cloud Firestore Security Rules and is an efficient way of comparing two `Map` objects.
Since `request.resource.data` and `resource.data` are maps, `MapDiff` is perfect for this.

### [`Map.diff()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map#diff)

In order to use any of the `MapDiff` functionality, you will first have to call `diff` on your map. This is very easy and looks like this:

```js
request.resource.data.diff(resource.data) // Now you have a MapDiff object!
```

#### [`affectedKeys`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff#affectedKeys)

The `MapDiff.affectedKeys` function is the most useful because it  combines `addedKeys`, `removedKeys`, and `changedKeys`. This means that `affectedKeys` is what will solve the problem from the original question.
This means that all of:

```js
allow update: if request.resource.data.size() == 6
              && request.resource.data.likes == resource.data.likes
              && request.resource.data.name == resource.data.name
              && request.resource.data.date == resource.data.date
              && request.resource.data.body == resource.data.body
              && request.resource.data.title == resource.data.title
              && request.resource.data.cakes is int;
```

Turns into just:

```js
allow update: if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['cakes'])
              && request.resource.data.cakes is int;
```

So `affectedKeys` returns a [`rules.Set`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Set) of all keys that are affected between the two maps, i.e. added, removed, or changed.

#### [`addedKeys`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff#addedKeys)

This works the same way `affectedKeys` does, now only returning a set with *added* keys.

```js
{'cakes': 1}.diff({}).addedKeys() == ['cakes'].toSet() // true
```

#### [`removedKeys`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff#removedKeys)

`MapDiff.removedKeys` is the opposite of `MapDiff.addedKeys` and returns a set of only the keys *removed* between the two maps:

```js
{}.diff({'cakes': 1}).removedKeys() == ['cakes'].toSet() // true
```

#### [`changedKeys`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff#changedKeys)

`MapDiff.changedKeys` returns a `Set` of all keys that were changed between the two maps:

```js
{'cakes': 0}.diff({'cakes': 1, 'pies': 4}).changedKeys() == ['cakes'].toSet() //true
```

A change is whenever the values in both sets are *not **equal***.

#### [`unchangedKeys`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff#unchangedKeys)

`MapDiff.unchangedKeys` is the opposite of `MapDiff.changedKeys` and returns a set of all keys that were *not* changed between the two maps, i.e. all keys with **equal** values:

```js
{'cakes': 0}.diff({'cakes': 0}).unchangedKeys() == ['cakes'].toSet() // true
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation! I wonder what are the behaviors of these methods when the compared maps are deeply nested? e.g. Will `affectedKeys` return anything if I do `{ 'level1': { 'level2': 0 } }.diff({ 'level1': { 'level2': 1 } }).affectedKeys()` ?   // expecting to return `['level1']`